# Add i18n to a markdoc + Nextjs project

Tags: next.js, markdoc

I am using [Markdoc](https://markdoc.dev/) + Nextjs for a documentation site and I want to add i18n.
I edited the next.config.js but I don't know how to use different .md file based on locale variable.

- src/pages/docs/analytics.en.md (locale=en)
- src/pages/docs/analytics.fr.md (locale=fr)
- src/pages/docs/analytics.es.md (locale=es)

**next.config.js.**

```
const withMarkdoc = require('@markdoc/next.js')

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'md'],
  experimental: {
    scrollRestoration: true,
  },
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de', 'it'],
    defaultLocale: 'en'
  },
}

module.exports = withMarkdoc()(nextConfig)
```

**src/pages/_document.jsx**

```
class MyDocument extends Document {

  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage


    console.log("Locale: ", ctx.locale)
  

    // Run the React rendering logic synchronously
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        // Useful for wrapping the whole react tree
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => {
            let pageProps = props.pageProps;

            //console.log("props", pageProps.markdoc.file)
            return <App {...props} />
        },
        // Useful for wrapping in a per-page basis
        enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
      })

    // Run the parent `getInitialProps`, it now includes the custom `renderPage`
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)


    return initialProps
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Html className="antialiased [font-feature-settings:'ss01']" lang="en">
        <Head>
          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: themeScript }} />
        </Head>

        <body className="bg-white dark:bg-slate-900">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )

  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

**src/pages/_app.jsx**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { slugifyWithCounter } from '@sindresorhus/slugify'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { Layout } from '@/components/Layout'

import 'focus-visible'
import '@/styles/tailwind.css'

function getNodeText(node) {
  let text = ''
  for (let child of node.children ?? []) {
    if (typeof child === 'string') {
      text += child
    }
    text += getNodeText(child)
  }
  return text
}

function collectHeadings(nodes, slugify = slugifyWithCounter()) {
  let sections = []

  for (let node of nodes) {
    if (node.name === 'h2' || node.name === 'h3') {
      let title = getNodeText(node)
      if (title) {
        let id = slugify(title)
        node.attributes.id = id
        if (node.name === 'h3') {
          if (!sections[sections.length - 1]) {
            throw new Error(
              'Cannot add `h3` to table of contents without a preceding `h2`'
            )
          }
          sections[sections.length - 1].children.push({
            ...node.attributes,
            title,
          })
        } else {
          sections.push({ ...node.attributes, title, children: [] })
        }
      }
    }

    sections.push(...collectHeadings(node.children ?? [], slugify))
  }

  return sections
}

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  let router = useRouter()

  let title = pageProps.markdoc?.frontmatter.title

  let pageTitle =
    pageProps.markdoc?.frontmatter.pageTitle ||
    `${pageProps.markdoc?.frontmatter.title} - Guides`

  let description = pageProps.markdoc?.frontmatter.description

  let tableOfContents = pageProps.markdoc?.content
    ? collectHeadings(pageProps.markdoc.content)
    : []

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
        {description && <meta name="description" content={description} />}
      </Head>
      <Layout title={title} tableOfContents={tableOfContents}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
```

**markdoc/nodes.js**

```
import { Fence } from '@/components/Fence'
import { nodes as defaultNodes } from '@markdoc/markdoc'

const nodes = {
  document: {
    render: undefined,
    allowComments: true
  },
  th: {
    ...defaultNodes.th,
    attributes: {
      ...defaultNodes.th.attributes,
      scope: {
        type: String,
        default: 'col',
      },
    },
  },
  fence: {
    render: Fence,
    attributes: {
      language: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  },
}

export default nodes
```

Comment: No, I gave up and now using Ruby on Rails with Strapi (self-hosted). More simplicity better maintenance